# Separation of random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

Let $A$ and $B$ be two random variables satisfying
\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}[A\neq B]=\epsilon.
\end{align}
Can it be said that there is a random variable $Z$ such that
\begin{align}
A=\begin{cases}
B&1-\epsilon\\
Z&\epsilon
\end{cases}.
\end{align}

Comment: What does $A=\begin{cases}B&\epsilon\\ Z&1-\epsilon\end{cases}$ mean?

Comment: If you define $Z=A$ then you likely have the result you want.

Comment: Giulio: A with probability of $\epsilon$ equals to $B$.

Comment: Michael: No, because $A$ is equal to $B$ with probability of $1-\epsilon$

Comment: @Math_Y : It seems you have edited the problem to reverse the roles of $B$ and $Z$. Why do you then still object to my first comment?

Answer (score 0):

First, what could
\begin{align}
A=\begin{cases}
B&1-\epsilon\\
Z&\epsilon
\end{cases}.
\end{align}
mean?

Informally, we can Let $Z$ have the conditional law of $A$ given $A\ne B$, i.e.,
$$\text{For all measurable} \; S, \quad P(Z \in S)=P(A \in S | A \ne B) \,,$$
then toss  a fresh coin with chance $\epsilon$ of heads,
and redefine $A$ to equal $Z$ if the coin lands heads and to equal $B$ if it lands tails.

Pedantically, the above is   informal shorthand for the following:

> On some probability space $\Omega'$, there are random variables $A',B',I,Z$
> such that

> - The joint law of $A',B'$ (a Borel measure on the plane) is the same as the joint law of $A,B$

> - $I$ is independent of $B',Z'$  (This is key!)

> - $P(I=1)=\epsilon=1-P(I=0)$.

> - $A'=IZ+(1-I)B'$

Indeed this is possible. On a suitable product space, let $B', I$ and $Z$ have their prescribed laws above, and be independent. Then together with
$A'=IZ+(1-I)B'$, all requirements are met.

Answer (score 0):

By the specifics you've described, you have a random variable $Z$ such that $P[A= B]=1-\epsilon$ and $P[A=Z]=\epsilon$ in $$Z(\omega)=\begin{cases} A(\omega)&\text{if }A(\omega)\neq B(\omega)\\ A(\omega)+5&\text{if }A(\omega)= B(\omega)\end{cases}$$